# How to fix "IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'" error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, owin

Trying to get an access token to use MS Graph in my WebApi. But keep getting this error,

> [TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.]
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +167 . .
>
> [IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is
> hidden]'.]
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__8.MoveNext()
> +662 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +99 . . [InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain
> configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.]
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__24.MoveNext()
> +1586 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +99

Tried all the fixes that I could find online.

I am using this [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/WebApp) as a reference for the auth part.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The search results shows many different reasons for this error. I get this error while testing IdentityServer4 samples on second time. Previously all the original samples worked. Also first sample(client Credential) also worked today. But after installing Telerik Fiddler all these were broken. Fiddler asked to click a button to configure some system default. It did something what I can't recall, but immediately I stop using fiddler. Then after I got this error I restarted the computer and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 25):

First, to solve this issue, you need to find out what the error is. Set this in your `Startup.cs` to reveal the real error (not recommended for a production environment):

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
}
```

In my case, I had a proxy issue running it locally inside the corporate network.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with a local proxy, how did you solve it ?

Comment: I think from memory I was using MailKit to send email and I had to set the proxy on the email client (in local dev) smtpClient.ProxyClient = new HttpProxyClient("proxy.mycompany.com", 80);

Comment: @RobertBrooker If I have to try this in the test environment (not in local debugging mode). Where will the log be present? I am using NLog, I have set `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII` to true (outside the `env.IsDevelopment()` `if` condition). Yet the log shows `IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.`

Comment: @Sampath If the `ShowPII = true` is run then it should be in the exception message. I'm not sure what is going wrong in your case.

Comment: `PII logging is ON` is coming now. The error is `IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000xx0-0x00-0000-xxxx-0000x00x0x00/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'., InnerException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.. `. I have to search on this now. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I faced the below issue

[IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.] Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__8.MoveNext() +662 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99 . . [InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.] Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__24.MoveNext() +1586 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99

the below Solution has fixed my problem.
I added the below code in startup.cs

**System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;**

Note: To get the detail about the exception , Add the below line. you will able to more detail about this issue.

**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;**

Comment: "...Tls12" fixed `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.` inner exception for me. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I got a similar error when creating a new Blazor App -> Blazor Server App with Individual User Accounts -> Connect to an existing user store in the cloud (Azure AD B2C).

[image]

> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is
>   hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
>   HttpResponseMessage: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see
>   https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content:
>   '[PII is hidden. For more details, see
>   https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
>   from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see
>   https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)

Make sure domain is set to your `Azure AD B2C` domain and not the full `App ID URI` in `appsettings.json`. For example use `<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com` instead of `<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/api`. Also look at AzureAdB2C -> Instance in `appsettings.json`. I had the value `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp` set here as default but it does not work, when I changed it to `https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/` everything started working.

Comment: This solution solved my problem. using Blazor Server

Answer (score 4):

Same here, I have read through the below with no success. My setup was working but then I am trying to load it up on a different machine and am encountering this problem.

Here is the stack trace, I got http status 400 and 404 for the two different applications I was running.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   HIDDEN LINE
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.FeaturePolicy.FeaturePolicyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.ReferrerPolicy.ReferrerPolicyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XContentTypeOptions.XContentTypeOptionsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XXssProtection.XXssProtectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XFrameOptions.XFrameOptionsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.Csp.CspMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   HIDDEN LINE
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.FeaturePolicy.FeaturePolicyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.ReferrerPolicy.ReferrerPolicyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XContentTypeOptions.XContentTypeOptionsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XXssProtection.XXssProtectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.XFrameOptions.XFrameOptionsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.Csp.CspMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Other articles that discuss this error.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2337

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2672

https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnetcore/issues/10

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2186

Solution:
Turns out I did not have AzureAD configured in `appsettings.json`. I had forgot to set my `User Secrets` to configure AzureAD with valid credentials.

[image]

You will need to set the below credentials to your own for AzureAd.

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "TenantId": "SOMETHING.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "SOMETHING",
    "ClientSecret": "SOMETHING"

  }
}
```

Comment: You can get a more detailed error message when setting the following flag: IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

Comment: Where would you put this "flag" of yours?

Comment: @RubenSzekér in an ASP.NET app you can put this in Application_Start() of Global.asax.cs. In a .Net Core you can add this in ConfigureServices() of Startup.cs

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, it is because it has to go through the DockerNAT. (It may be that not everyone gets this IP address)

This is how I solved my issue:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Type ipconfig

You will get something like this.

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : **10.0.75.1**

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

3. Basically copy that IP address to your docker-compose.yml file

   services:

   webmvc:

   ```
   build:

     context: .\src\Web\WebMvc

     dockerfile: Dockerfile

   environment:

     - IdentityUrl=http://10.0.75.1:5000/ #Change IP and Port

   container_name: test

   ports:

     - "5200:80"

   networks:

     - frontend

   depends_on:

     - tokenserver #your identityserver4 service
   ```
4. Other things to check are:

Make sure that on your Startup.cs under ConfigureServices (WebMvc project) you have the following and that they are spelled correctly on your yml file.

```
        var identityUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl");
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;             
            options.Authority = identityUrl.ToString();
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5200/"; //Change to your mvc address
            options.ClientId ="mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType =  "code id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
```

5. In addition to this you may want to open ports on your firewall. In my case I had to open the port 5000.

a. Open control panel

b. System And Security

c. Windows Defender Firewall

d. Advanced Settings

e. Inbound Settings => New Rule..

f. Rule Type => Port ==> Click Next

g. Select TCP under protocol

h. Specific local ports => Enter 5000

i. Click Next => Select Allow the connection

j. Click Next

k. I left all checked under When does the rule apply?

l. Click Next => Enter Docker Port => Click Finish

Comment: Darn, spent a couple of days faffing around with developer certificates etc just to find that changing the ip address to the docker NAT one works. Thanks, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I added the below code to `startup.cs`, and it fixed my problem:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Yep that was the culprit in my case... Heaps thanks,

Answer (score 0):

it occurs due to project runnable setting is ticked in iisexpress change to project name then it will works.
[there is multiple option project runnable so select project name inplace of any other ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax7ab.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling to get Azure AD B2C running in a Visual Studio project, see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server

In a nutshell, there is a tool that you can run that will configure all settings for you.

This will save you tons of headache in getting the many settings correct that are required.

Answer (score 0):

My newbie mistake in appsettings.json, was not using the right id numbers;

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "(guid of the tenant)",
    "ClientId": "(guid of the registered application)",
    "ClientSecret": "(registered application, certification and secret, id of secret)"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue was resolved by adding below code in startup.cs inside configuration method.
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

Comment: This just enables extra logging of Personally Identifiable Information so that the `[PII is hidden]'.]` part of OP's log gets filled; it cannot have resolved the problem.

Comment: This worked for me...everything else I tried had failed.