# Sign Up/In not working in ASP. NET Core application: Azure B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal, azure-identity

We configured user flow with Google as identity provider. Followed the Azure-Sample repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C) in building an ASP.NET Core web app with .NET 6.

appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "3ae27e38-90a3-43c7-9bac-8d3bf33227f9",
    "Domain": "b2ctenant.b2clogin.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile" // Optional profile editing policy
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
```

https://localhost:44316

[image]

Getting exception when users select `Sign Up/In` option

> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see
> https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII of
> type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' is hidden. For more
> details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]',
> HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden.
> For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
> address, CancellationToken cancel)
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(string
> address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
> cancel)
> nvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more
> details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
> cancel)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties
> properties)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties
> properties)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties
> properties)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext
> context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/54647917/1841839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one application and granted **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I cloned the same GitHub sample and updated **`appsettings.json`** file same as you like below:

[image]

I **ran** the above sample and got below screen:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Sign Up/In`** button, I got same error as you like below:

[image]

> **Note** that, you are giving ***wrong value*** to your Domain parameter in your **`appsettings.json`** file. You need to change *value* of Domain parameter that can be found here:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I changed value of Domain parameter in my
**`appsettings.json`** file like below:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Sign Up/In`** button now by running the sample, I got the login screen with **Google** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:** [Configure authentication using Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app?tabs=visual-studio#step-4-configure-the-sample-web-app)